# ASP.NET MVC "strong" relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parent-child, recursive-descent

Currently I have an Model that's recursive (one of its properties is of the same type).

For example:

```
public class Page
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Description{ get; set; }
  public int ParentID  {get; set; }

}
```

Now, when I want to access someone's parent, I will have to get the ParentID, query the database and find the Page. What I want is that I can do the following:

```
Page page = _db.GetFirstPage();
Page pagesParent = page.Parent;
```

How can I achieve that? I've tried the following:

```
public class Page
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Description{ get; set; }
  public int ParentID  {get; set; }
  public Page Parent { get; set; }

}
```

Because I thought the entity framework would automagically assume Parent is linked to parentID, but that doesn't work.

---

Alright here is all my code:
The controller method is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var pages = _db.Pages;
        ViewBag.Pages = new SelectList(pages,"ID","Description");
        return View();
    }
```

In the view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Pages", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentID)
    </div>
```

The model:

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Page Parent { get; set; }
```

When I go to the Create View. I get a list of all the Pages, but when I create them, the new Page's Parent property is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `ParentID` property nullable because every page will **not** have a parent. Also make `Parent` property virtual to allow lazy loading.

```
public class Page
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Description{ get; set; }

  public int? ParentID  {get; set; }
  public virtual Page Parent { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Awesome, that's what I had first. However, in my Create View, I cannot add the relation trough a DropDownList, `@Html.DropDownList("ParentID", ViewBag.Pages as SelectList)` where ViewBag.Pages is set in the controller as a list of all the pages.

Comment: @Timo can you explain what you mean by `I cannot add the relation`? does the `ParentID` get updated?

Comment: Yeah the ParentID does get updated, but the Parent property doesn't. Also I noticed in my database table I have both a ParentID, and a PageID field. So it seems like ParentID is just seen as a regular property.

Comment: @Timo `Parent` property will not be updated because your entity is not created by EF. And it should not matter since EF will use the `ParentID` value to update the database. You need both fields in the database. EF will create a FK between those two fields.

Comment: Uhm, sorry I don't seem to understand that. If the Parent property doesn't get updated, why do we add it then to the model?

Comment: @Timo As you can see from the `Page` class definition, there isn't any code to automatically update the `Parent` when `ParentID` is set. EF creates [proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx) of the `Page` class which will have that update logic. So there is a difference between EF creating instances of `Page` class and you(or MVC) creating new instance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4120/discussion-between-timo-willemsen-and-eranga)

Answer (score 1):

EF of course can handle recursive association and also can automagically look up associations for you. So this code is ok:

```
public class Page
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Description{ get; set; }
  public int ParentID  {get; set; }
  public Page Parent { get; set; }

}
```

Your problem is the EF does not automatically load relations if your are not using lazy loading. You have two options:

- Turn on lazy loading for the Parent property as making the property virtual (
  in this case EF can override it to do the the loding
- Explicitly tell EF with the [Include](http://romiller.com/2010/07/14/ef-ctp4-tips-tricks-include-with-lambda/) method to when you request a Page also load the associated Parent objects. So your
  GetFirstPage() method should contain something like this:

  ```
  efContext.Pages.Include(p => p.Parent).First();
  ```